# ImportError: cannot import name 'Iterable' from 'collections'

Tags: python

Пытался импортировать библиотеку vk, но вылезала такая ошибка:
ImportError: cannot import name 'Iterable' from 'collections'
может это связано с тем что у меня есть библиотека vk_api?

Answer (score 1):

Это от того что у тебя python версии 3.9.
Решение: oткрой в папке "*Python\Lib\site-packages\vk*" файл "*utils.py*", в нём строку "**from collections import Iterable**" замени на  "**from collections.abc import Iterable**" и будет тебе счастье.